# angular.js Internet Explorer 11 cannot inject $location

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use `$location` in `angular.js` to provide `queryparams`. My code below works perfectly in Firefox, but doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11. If I remove the `$location` code, then it works.

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode( true );
}]);

app.controller('appName',
        ['$scope', '$location', '$http', function($scope, $location, $http) {
            alert(JSON.stringify($location));
}]);
```

The error is difficult to understand:

> Error: Invalid argument.
>       at xa (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9 /angular.min.js:147:373)
>       at hd (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js:97:498)
>       ...

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there another way I can extract the `queryparams` from IE 11 besides `$location.search()`?

Thanks!

Comment: try adding  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" /> to your index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue is in my html file:

I previously had:

```
<base href="appname">
```

I needed to change this to:

```
<base href="/appname/">
```

Firefox was forgiving of the missing '/', but IE wasn't.

This solved the problem.